# MySQL Data C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException while Database.CreateIfNotExists

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I'm getting a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException when I try to execute Database.CreateIfNotExists. The model classes were created by code first from database. I'm using EF 6.4.4, MySql.Data 8.0.20 and MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.20.

[image]

In the following pictures you can see the model classes.

Class 1:

[image: Class1]

Class2 :

[image: Class2]

Class 3 :

[image: Class3]

Class 4 :

[image: Class4]

Class 5:

[image: Class 5]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post the actual code, with the proper formating.

Comment: Don't show us pictures of code. Post the **actual exception message**.

Comment: Just added the error message